# How do I wait until a variable reaches a certain number to do something?

Tags: c++, algorithm, conditional-statements

I am creating a game in C++. In this game, I have created a class called `Player`. The `Player` class has an attribute called `magic`. This attribute is an integer and constantly goes up throughout the game, when a user does something or accomplishes a task, they can gain `magic`. Once it reaches a certain point, the user gets a new spell, the spells are held in an array in the player class.

I want to be able to check this attribute throughout the game to see if it has reached a certain level.

I was thinking of just checking every time the `magic` attribute goes up, but this could add a lot of conditionals every time it does so. Such as:

```
user.magic++ 
if(user.magic == 2) {
    //Give a new spell 
}
else if(user.magic == 3) {
    //Give a new spell
}
```

And do this every time the `magic` attribute is updated. This seems like it would take a lot of time and effort to constantly type this. Should I put the code above in a function and just run it every time the `magic` updates?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: other languages / environments especially GUIs use "observable" objects (e.g. `addEventListener` in Javascript + DOM) where you add a callback function that gets called when the variable changes

Comment: I don't see any issues doing it the way you want to do it. That looks ok to me

Comment: @Lorenzo think about what happens if the `user` has attained `magic` 3 and the function is called more than once.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand what youre saying, but there would be no chance of that happening, the function would only be called when `magic` was increased, so `magic `would never be the same as before. This is not the way I am doing it (see which answer I chose), but this _technically_ would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step: you decouple the user.magic from the spells available. Reason: maybe in the future you want to assign spells for NPC-es as well, not only users.

```
struct spell {
  int type;
  int cost;
  int damage;
}

static const spell walk_on_water={SURVIVAL, 10, 0};
static const spell resurect={DARK_MAGIC, 100, 0};
static const spell fireball_minor={OFFENSIVE, 30, 4};
static const spell fireball_big={OFFENSIVE, 300, 25};

void getSpellsForMagicLevel(int userMagic, std::vector<const spell&>& resultHere) {
  resultHere.clear();
  switch(useMagic) {
    case 1:
      resultHere.push_back(walk_on_water);
      break;
    case 2:
      resultHere.push_back(walk_on_water);
      resultHere.push_back(fireball_minor);
      break;
    //...
    case 10:
      resultHere.push_back(walk_on_water);
      resultHere.push_back(resurect);
      resultHere.push_back(fireball_minor);
      resultHere.push_back(fireball_big);
      break;
  }
}
```

and then you call this single function any time you want to know what available spells are there for a `player.magic`

---

Then you note that user's spell inventory only changes when the `magic` modifies (up - due to increased experience - or down e.g. due to a damaging potion) - so why rely on calling this function again and again? So:

```
class Player {
protected:
  int magic;
  std::vector<const spell&> spell_inventory;

// ...
  void set_magic_level(int newMagicLevel) {
    if(this->magic != newMagicLevel) { // do nothing if no change
       this->magic = newMagicLevel;
       getSpellsForMagicLevel(this->magic, this->spell_inventory);
    }
  }
// ...
public:
// ...
  int get_magic_level() const {
    return this->magic;
  }
};

class User : public Player {
  //...
public:

  void newExperience(const Event& somethingThatHappened)
  {
     switch(somethingThatHappened.type) {
     case EXPERIENCE_THRESHOLD_REACHED:
       this->set_magic_level(this->get_magic_level()+1);
       break;
     case DUMBING_POTION:
       this->set_magic_level(
          this->get_magic_level()-somethingThatHappened.get_damage()
       );
       break;
     // etc...
     }
  }
};

class NonPlayerCharacter : public Player {
  //...
public:
  // NPC-es don't evolve, they are just spawned
  // So no newExperience method for them.
};
```

Comment: (one can only wish the downvoter have courage to explain)

Comment: Maybe because your answer is kind of "overkill". It does not directly answer OP's question. I upvoted you because of the quality of your answer and the fact that it shows a good use of encapsulation (which OP should learn asap). People seem to downvote for any reasons...

Comment: @Cedric " a good use of encapsulation (which OP should learn asap)." The very purpose for my overkill - teach them fishing (instead setting them afire :) )

Comment: Haha I do understand why! I was just answering to your question! Anyway, good work on that answer! :) There should be less downvoters and more people that answer like you on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

Make the `.magic` member variable `private` so that the only way to increase magic is to call a method such as `user.IncrementMagic()` rather than being allowed to say `user.magic++` directly. Then, the implementation of the method might look something like:

```
Player::IncrementMagic()
{
    magic++;
    CheckUpdatedMagicLevel();
}
Player::CheckUpdatedMagicLevel()
{
    if(magic == 2)
    {
        // etc
    }
    // etc
}
```

If needed, you could also write further methods that manipulate `magic` in different ways—e.g. `DecrementMagic` or `SetNewMagicLevel(x)`. These methods would also call `CheckUpdatedMagicLevel()` internally.

Answer (score 1):

How about use a map? so you can use the number of mana required to unlock certain spells (aka int) as keys and store strings or other implements for unlocked spells and grant the player such spells. I mean, technically it is better than having tons of hardcoded if loops, in this implementation you can just change the map and use the same function.

edited for another way to design this, you give the player all the spells from the beginning but limit it by "can only cast certain spell when match MAGIC requirements", which you can still use map as a handy tool

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll try this out.

Comment: I mean, you can even have another method to read from files and store spells info into the map, which it will be easier to update the game data as they are pretty much loaded from configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the value "constantly" (with a timer? every time a certain command is issued?) is possible, but then your step of `1` to add a new spell is way too small. It would mean that on every action you get a new spell!

Instead, use something like this: set an `experience` value to `0`. Then, in your main loop (that same timer, or whatever you are using), increase this value. If it reaches some reasonable value, say, `100`, add a new spell and reset the `experience` value back to `0`.

Comment: I'll edit my question to be more clear, to acquire magic, you must accomplish tasks, certain tasks will give you a new magic quota, its not on a timer.

Comment: @Alice: the idea is the same, regardless of when the variable is incremented. You test for a maximum of 'experience', and if reached, add a spell; then reset that value, so a next event can be triggered.